# In-App Purchase, how to get products which are have "Waiting for review" status

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have published app, and I added new products for In-App Purchase. Status is "Waiting for review"  now. How can I programmatically get status of my products?

I know that when if you will try to buy this product, you get error code 0. But I need to check all my products id before user starts buy them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Xcode or Application Loader, you already have Transporter (Apple’s command-line tool) installed. 
You can find it in :
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin

Transporter have a Lookup Mode allow you to retrieve your app’s current metadata and will create an
App Store package at the set destination.

Type following command in the Terminal app (navigate to directory where Transporter is installed):
$ iTMSTransporter -m lookupMetadata -u [iTunes Connect user name] -p [iTunes Connect password] -vendor_id [App SKU] -destination [destination path for App Store Package] -subitemtype InAppPurchase -subitemids [requested_purchase_ID]

if you have several products to check. Set purchase_IDs comma-separated list in subitemids.